# Does PythonTutor C++ automatically use long longs when storing longs?

Tags: c++

I am currently writing a program that uses a very large number.    My code is as below:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    long num = 4003600000000014;

    // do some stuff
}
```

Before I ran my code, I checked my program using PythonTutor, in C++ mode.  All went well, and it gave me the output I expected.

However, upon running in VSCode, I get an error:

```
warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
     long num = 4003600000000014;
```

I understand that this error occurred because I didn't use `long long`, but why did it work in PythonTutor?  Does it automatically use `long long`s?  Why?

Edit: I made this question before I realized that different machines used different sizes for the same type, and I can instead use fixed-width integers/auto.

Comment: sizes of `long int` vary. Consider using `int64_t` or `auto`

Comment: One way of checking how long a `long` can be on your platform is with [numeric_limits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits). On my computer, 64-bit windows, MSVC tells me the max is 2147483647 but if I check the same code in GCC on WSL it tells me 9223372036854775807.